# How to create system user under facebook business account without creating any APp for client business

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I have to create system user under client business manager but without creating any app through graph php api. My scenario is such way - I want to access client business account as a partner to create ad campaigns. I found one way from facebook developer documentation that create business on behalf relationship. But after followed few step it require client system token & for creating that token it asking app first. But why client will create app to only for system token?

Pls help to get solution for this. Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You can not interact with the API, without having an app id first.

Comment: Thanks. I have our business APP created & API also working. But we want to create ads for another client using our app(platform). We have taken required permission also during facebook authentication.